# Json Nested Complex Array to Web Api 2.0 Controller Action

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

Ok gang. I am having what seems to be a very popular but very unsolved (at least for me) problem.  I have the following request body in Fiddler:

```
{
    "Type": "WQ",
    "Customer": "1600",
    "JobNbr": "1zAlpha - BLAHDYBLOO",
    "Delivery": 1,
    "Pickup": 1,
    "DelInst": "Location: Earth
    ",
    "StartDate": "2017-02-28",
    "StartTime": "1700",
    "EndDate": "2017-03-15",
    "EndTime": "1700",
    "CustTransactionId": "555",
"EquipmentItems": {
  "EquipmentItem":
 [
        {
          "Equipment": "0500006",
          "CatID": "050",
          "ClassID": "0006",
          "LineSeq": "1",
          "Quantity": "001"
        },
        {
          "Equipment": "0500007",
          "CatID": "050",
          "ClassID": "0007",
          "LineSeq": "2",
          "Quantity": "001"
        }
      ]},
    "CustomerFields": {
      "blah": "12345",
      "blah blah": "123",
      "blah blah blah": "WHATEVER"
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I have a complex "Reservation" object that contains a nested array of "Equipment" objects as well as a complex list of key value pairs that a customer may send us which we call CustomerFields.

When I send this to my Controller's action through fiddler, the parent class comes in as expected, but the nested Equipments array and the CustomerFields objects come in null.

My headers look like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01
Host: localhost:51493
Content-Length: 1209
```

My action signature looks like:

```
Post([FromBody]Reservation reservation)
```

And each class is decorated with [JsonObjec] or [JsonProperty] respectively and I have tried removing the Json "names" from the json body as well.  What do I need to do to get my fully populated object inside my controller from fiddler?  Do I need to make json data adjustments?  Code adjustments?  Both?  I'm at a complete loss.  I have tried so many different permutations that listing them would be counterproductive at this point.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Reservation Class Definition:

```
[JsonObject]
    public partial class Reservation : IReservation
    {
        #region private fields        
        private string companyField;
        private int? locationField;
        private ReservationType typeField;
        private string customerField;
        private string custTransactionIDField;
        private Guid sbrTransactionIDField;
        private string licenseField;
        private string dlStateField;
        private string jobNbrField;
        private bool deliveryField;
        private bool pickupField;
        private string deliveryInstructionsField;
        private DateTime startDateField;
        private DateTime endDateField;
        private string customerPOField;
        private string webUserField;
        private bool rPPFlagField;
        private bool fuelFlagField;
        private decimal deliveryChargeField;
        private decimal pickupChargeField;
        private CustomerDataList customerDataField;
        private EquipmentItems itemsField;
        #endregion

        #region Public properties
        /// <remarks/>
        public int? ReservationNo { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Company
        {
            get
            {
                return this.companyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.companyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public int? Location
        {
            get
            {
                return this.locationField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.locationField = (value != null) ?  value : -1;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public ReservationType Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Customer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CustTransactionID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.custTransactionIDField != null ? custTransactionIDField : string.Empty;              
            }

            set
            {
                this.custTransactionIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public Guid SBRTransactionID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.sbrTransactionIDField;
            }

            set
            {
                this.sbrTransactionIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string License
        {
            get
            {
                return this.licenseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.licenseField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string DlState
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dlStateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dlStateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string JobNbr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.jobNbrField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.jobNbrField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool Delivery
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deliveryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.deliveryField = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Pickup
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pickupField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pickupField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string DeliveryInstructions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deliveryInstructionsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.deliveryInstructionsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public System.DateTime StartDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.startDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.startDateField = value;
            }
        }

        public string StartTime { get; set; }
        public string EndTime { get; set; }
        /// <remarks/>
        public System.DateTime EndDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.endDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.endDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CustomerPO
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerPOField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerPOField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string WebUser
        {
            get
            {
                return this.webUserField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.webUserField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool RPPFlag
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rPPFlagField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rPPFlagField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool FuelFlag
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fuelFlagField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fuelFlagField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal DeliveryCharge
        {
            get
            {
                return this.deliveryChargeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.deliveryChargeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public decimal PickupCharge
        {
            get
            {
                return this.pickupChargeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.pickupChargeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("EquipmentItems", IsNullable = false)]
        [JsonProperty]
        public EquipmentItems Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public CustomerDataList CustomerData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerDataField = value;
            }
        }

        List<IItemData> IReservation.Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField.ToList<IItemData>();
            }

            set
            {
                SetItems(value);
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
        #endregion

        private void SetItems(List<IItemData> items)
        {            

            this.itemsField = ((EquipmentItems)((IEnumerable<EquipmentItem>)items.Select(e => e.CatID == e.CatID)));


        }
    }
    #endregion
```

EquipmentItems Definition:

```
[JsonObject]
public partial class EquipmentItems : List<EquipmentItem>
{ }

[JsonObject]

    public partial class EquipmentItem : IItemData
    {
        #region Private fields
        private string equipmentIDField;
        private string catIDField;
        private string classIDField;
        private string lineSequenceField;
        private string quantityField;
        private string toolFlexField;
        private string hourlyRateField;
        private string dailyRateField;
        private string weeklyRateField;
        private string monthlyRateField;
        private string minRateField;
        private bool daysOverField;
        private bool weeksOverField;
        private bool monthsOverField;
        #endregion

        #region Public properties
        /// <remarks/>
        public string Equipment
        {
            get
            {
                return this.equipmentIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.equipmentIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string CatID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.catIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.catIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ClassID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.classIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.classIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string LineSeq
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lineSequenceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lineSequenceField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string Quantity
        {
            get
            {
                return this.quantityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.quantityField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ToolFlex
        {
            get
            {
                return this.toolFlexField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.toolFlexField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string HrRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.hourlyRateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.hourlyRateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string DayRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dailyRateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dailyRateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string WkRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.weeklyRateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.weeklyRateField = value;
            }
        }

        public string MinRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.minRateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.minRateField = value;
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
        public string MoRate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.monthlyRateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.monthlyRateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool DayOver
        {
            get
            {
                return this.daysOverField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.daysOverField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool WkOver
        {
            get
            {
                return this.weeksOverField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.weeksOverField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public bool MoOver
        {
            get
            {
                return this.monthsOverField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.monthsOverField = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

There is almost 0% chance there is a delta between the json and the class defs as I used automation tools for both.  But if you can help me figure out just the EquipmentItems array, that will be enough.  Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps you could include your Reservation classes? In my experience, this occurs when there's a mismatch between the Json data and the target object.

Comment: I also note that EquipmentItems is an object that contains EquiptmentItem, which is an array of objects. Is that correct?

Comment: @john  Yes that is correct

Comment: Your objects don't match your JSON in the way I previously mentioned. In your C# classes, EquipmentItems is a list of EquipmentItem. In your JSON EquipmentItems is an object which contains EquipmentItem, which is an array of something.

Comment: OK, can you advise on what I need to change in the json to make it match the class?

Comment: If it is OK, I'd like to focus only on the Equipment Item for now.  For this question, CustomerFields is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your json isn't quite correct if you're expecting that class structure. I've removed the array under EquipmentItem and changed EquipmentItems into an array:

```
{
    "Type": "WQ",
    "Customer": "1600",
    "JobNbr": "1zAlpha - BLAHDYBLOO",
    "Delivery": 1,
    "Pickup": 1,
    "DelInst": "Location: Earth
            ",
    "StartDate": "2017-02-28",
    "StartTime": "1700",
    "EndDate": "2017-03-15",
    "EndTime": "1700",
    "CustTransactionId": "555",
    "EquipmentItems": [{
            "Equipment": "0500006",
            "CatID": "050",
            "ClassID": "0006",
            "LineSeq": "1",
            "Quantity": "001"
        }, {
            "Equipment": "0500007",
            "CatID": "050",
            "ClassID": "0007",
            "LineSeq": "2",
            "Quantity": "001"
        }
    ],
    "CustomerFields": {
        "blah": "12345",
        "blah blah": "123",
        "blah blah blah": "WHATEVER"
    }
}
```

---

```
[JsonObject]
public partial class Reservation : IReservation
{
    #region private fields        
    private string companyField;
    private int? locationField;
    private ReservationType typeField;
    private string customerField;
    private string custTransactionIDField;
    private Guid sbrTransactionIDField;
    private string licenseField;
    private string dlStateField;
    private string jobNbrField;
    private bool deliveryField;
    private bool pickupField;
    private string deliveryInstructionsField;
    private DateTime startDateField;
    private DateTime endDateField;
    private string customerPOField;
    private string webUserField;
    private bool rPPFlagField;
    private bool fuelFlagField;
    private decimal deliveryChargeField;
    private decimal pickupChargeField;
    private CustomerDataList customerDataField;
    private List<EquipmentItem> itemsField;
    #endregion

    #region Public properties
    /// <remarks/>
    public int? ReservationNo { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Company
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int? Location
    {
        get
        {
            return this.locationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.locationField = (value != null) ?  value : -1;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ReservationType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Customer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CustTransactionID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.custTransactionIDField != null ? custTransactionIDField : string.Empty;              
        }

        set
        {
            this.custTransactionIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public Guid SBRTransactionID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sbrTransactionIDField;
        }

        set
        {
            this.sbrTransactionIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string License
    {
        get
        {
            return this.licenseField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.licenseField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DlState
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dlStateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dlStateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string JobNbr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.jobNbrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.jobNbrField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool Delivery
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deliveryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deliveryField = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Pickup
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pickupField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pickupField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DeliveryInstructions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deliveryInstructionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deliveryInstructionsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.startDateField = value;
        }
    }

    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime EndDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.endDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.endDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CustomerPO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerPOField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customerPOField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string WebUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this.webUserField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.webUserField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool RPPFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rPPFlagField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rPPFlagField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool FuelFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fuelFlagField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fuelFlagField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal DeliveryCharge
    {
        get
        {
            return this.deliveryChargeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.deliveryChargeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal PickupCharge
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pickupChargeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pickupChargeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("EquipmentItems", IsNullable = false)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EquipmentItems")]
    public List<EquipmentItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public CustomerDataList CustomerData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customerDataField = value;
        }
    }

    List<IItemData> IReservation.Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField.ToList<IItemData>();
        }

        set
        {
            SetItems(value);
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    #endregion

    private void SetItems(List<IItemData> items)
    {            

        this.itemsField = ((List<EquipmentItem>)((IEnumerable<EquipmentItem>)items.Select(e => e.CatID == e.CatID)));


    }
}
#endregion  



[JsonObject]

public partial class EquipmentItem : IItemData
{
    #region Private fields
    private string equipmentIDField;
    private string catIDField;
    private string classIDField;
    private string lineSequenceField;
    private string quantityField;
    private string toolFlexField;
    private string hourlyRateField;
    private string dailyRateField;
    private string weeklyRateField;
    private string monthlyRateField;
    private string minRateField;
    private bool daysOverField;
    private bool weeksOverField;
    private bool monthsOverField;
    #endregion

    #region Public properties
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Equipment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.equipmentIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.equipmentIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CatID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.catIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.catIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ClassID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.classIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.classIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string LineSeq
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lineSequenceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lineSequenceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.quantityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ToolFlex
    {
        get
        {
            return this.toolFlexField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.toolFlexField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HrRate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hourlyRateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hourlyRateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DayRate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dailyRateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dailyRateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string WkRate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.weeklyRateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.weeklyRateField = value;
        }
    }

    public string MinRate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.minRateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.minRateField = value;
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    public string MoRate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.monthlyRateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.monthlyRateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool DayOver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.daysOverField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.daysOverField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool WkOver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.weeksOverField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.weeksOverField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool MoOver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.monthsOverField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.monthsOverField = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Is there any way I can make this work without changing the class definition?

Comment: @DJ You don't have to change the class definition - this was just in case you had any further issues, so that you can analyse if it's an issue with your class or not. The changed json should work with your current class now, unless I've missed other issues.

Comment: Oh thanks for that clarification.  I did try your json in fiddler and no joy

Comment: @DJ Try this. For some reason EquipmentItems in your C# class is defined as "Items", which is different to the JSON file. I updated the JsonProperty attribute to reflect this. I hope you don't mind, I also took the liberty of removing EquipmentItems during my testing. Feel free to put it back.

Comment: OMG!!!  That did it!  The funny thing is, that was the original definition of the EquipmentItems property.  In 1 of the 100's of attempts to fix this, I changed it to a class object hoping that would help.  
Thanks so much @John